# Starting animation with a button Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, button, jbutton

I'd like to create an animation of a few objects ("Spaceships") on the screen, with a start button. This is what I have so far:

```
public class SpaceGame extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    //The list of spaceships that should be painted
    LinkedList<Spaceship> playingList = new LinkedList<Spaceship>(); 
    Timer t = new Timer(5, this);

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        ListIterator<Spaceship> iter = playingList.listIterator();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            Spaceship s = iter.next();
            s.moveSpaceship();

        }
        repaint();
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        for (Spaceship s : playingList)
            s.drawSpaceship(g);
        t.start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpaceGame game = new SpaceGame();
        JFrame fr = new JFrame();
        fr.setTitle("SPACE GAME");
        fr.setSize(990,690);
        fr.add(game);

        game.playingList .add(new Spaceship(3, 0, 570));
        game.playingList .add(new Spaceship(1, 250, 570));
        game.playingList .add(new Spaceship(2, 500, 570));


        JButton start = new JButton("START");
        start.addActionListener(game);
        fr.add(start,BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        fr.setVisible(true);
        fr.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }

}
```

where:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class Spaceship {
    int initialSpeed;
    int locX, locY; //current location 

    public Spaceship(int initalSpeed, int initX, int initY) {
        this.initialSpeed = initalSpeed;
        locX = initX;
        locY = initY;
    }

    public void drawSpaceship(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g.fillOval(locX, locY, 100, 40);
    }

    public void moveSpaceship() {
        locY -= initialSpeed;
    }


}
```

Of cousre the idea is that pressing the button would trigger the animation. The problem is that the animation would start automaticaly without the start button being pressed, and then when it ends, the button has no effect. How can I fix this?

Comment: Do not, ever, start a `Timer` in `paintComponent`, in fact, you should do NOTHING but paint the current state of the component in the paint methods.  Instead, the `Timer` should be started by some other action, independently of the paint process

Comment: The other problem, as far as I can see is, the `Timer` and the button are using the same `actionPerformed` method, which doesn't make sense.  Provide a method in your `SpaceGame` which can be called by the buttons `ActionListener`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with the glaringly obvious...

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    for (Spaceship s : playingList)
        s.drawSpaceship(g);
    t.start();
}
```

Call `t.start` inside `paintComponent` is a very, very, very bad idea.  You do not control the paint process (ie when `paintComponent` gets called), so it might be called at any time for any number of reasons, often in quick succession.

You should have a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) for more details about how painting works in Swing

Painting should simply paint the current state of the component and nothing else.

The second problem is the fact that both the `Timer` and the button are calling the same `actionPerformed` method, which doesn't really make sense. In fact, in a perfect world, you wouldn't implement `ActionListener` directly like this and instead make use of [Anonymous Classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) which would guard against outside classes calling the method directly or indirectly.

So, what's the solution?  Add a method to your `SpaceGame` which can be called to start the animation, something like...

```
public class SpaceGame extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
  //The list of spaceships that should be painted

  LinkedList<Spaceship> playingList = new LinkedList<Spaceship>();
  Timer t = new Timer(5, this);

  public void start() {
    if (t.isRunning()) {
      return;
    }
    t.start();
  }

  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    ListIterator<Spaceship> iter = playingList.listIterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
      Spaceship s = iter.next();
      s.moveSpaceship();

    }
    repaint();
  }

  public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    for (Spaceship s : playingList) {
      s.drawSpaceship(g);
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        SpaceGame game = new SpaceGame();
        JFrame fr = new JFrame();
        fr.setTitle("SPACE GAME");
        // This is unadvisable :/
        fr.setSize(990, 690);
        fr.add(game);

        game.playingList.add(new Spaceship(3, 0, 570));
        game.playingList.add(new Spaceship(1, 250, 570));
        game.playingList.add(new Spaceship(2, 500, 570));

        JButton start = new JButton("START");
        start.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
          @Override
          public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {
            game.start();
          }
        });
        fr.add(start, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        fr.setVisible(true);
        fr.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Then update your main method to call it...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      SpaceGame game = new SpaceGame();
      JFrame fr = new JFrame();
      fr.setTitle("SPACE GAME");
      // This is unadvisable :/
      fr.setSize(990, 690);
      fr.add(game);

      game.playingList.add(new Spaceship(3, 0, 570));
      game.playingList.add(new Spaceship(1, 250, 570));
      game.playingList.add(new Spaceship(2, 500, 570));

      JButton start = new JButton("START");
      start.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {
          game.start();
        }
      });
      fr.add(start, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

      fr.setVisible(true);
      fr.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
  });
}
```